# How to create an event listener and infinite loop using python pyrogram

Tags: python, metatrader5, pyrogram

**Objective**

I am trying to create a python trading bot that can listen for messages from some telegram channels and at the same it should have an infinite loop that perform some function based on certain conditions

**what I have achieved**

Currently I'm able to listen for messages and perform decisions based on the receive messages from telegram using python pyrogram library

**Below is the my code**

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters
    
bot = Client(TELEGRAM_BOT_NAME, api_id=TELEGRAM_API_ID,api_hash=TELEGRAM_API_HASH)
@bot.on_message(filters.channel)
def my_handler(client, message):
       #....... code here
bot.run() 
    
#infinite loop
while True: 
    #--code here
```

**The problem**
I'm not able to run infinite loop (not evening running) while listening for the message from telegram at the same time.

How can this be achieved ?

Comment: if you can listen for messages and act on them, what is the infinite loop for?

Comment: I want to perform other function concurrently with message listening

Comment: I think you want to check out [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: Before calling `bot.run()`, create and start another thread, and do your work there.

Comment: Maybe `bot` has a method to schedule work based on a timer. Look.up its documentation.

Comment: multiprocessing and threading are two different solutions. Use of threading for firing a function when conditions change may be preferred.